# Include question closure in heartbeat

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, live-refresh

The heartbeat now includes post deletion (it updates live when a post is deleted), which was added recently (I still cannot find a reference for the new addition).

**Can we please also have the closure of questions included in the heartbeat?**

Meaning that if a question is closed while I'm viewing it, a banner will pop up or some such UX goodness to tell me that the question is now closed.

I know that there is something if I'm writing an answer and the question gets closed, but I'm usually not writing answers to questions when they are being closed, I'm usually monitoring their status until they are closed.

This would save Stack Exchange the overhead of me spamming <kbd>F5</kbd> until the question is closed.

Comment: Also, if someone could give me a reference to the announcement of the inclusion of post deletion in the heartbeat, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no announcement. It was recently implemented as a fix for a different pain point, and we'll announce all that once all the pieces are put together.

Comment: Oh, so is this planned for inclusion as well, or no?